# How is Apple able to provide indoor location using CoreLocation?

Tags: ios, maps, core-location, indoor-positioning-system

I found this `Sample Code` at Apple's Developer Site:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html

The discription says:

> Use Core Location to take a Latitude/Longitude position and project it
>   onto a flat floorplan. Demonstrates how to do the conversions between
>   a Geographic coordinate system (Latitude/Longitude), a floorplan PDF
>   coordinate system (x, y), and MapKit.

I have tried it and it works really well.
Basically, you provide a map image for a building and specify two coordinates manually. Then, using CoreLocation, it is converting latitude/longitute into (x,y) position.

My question is - how is it possible to grab latitude/longitude while indoors?
I have watched some Apple's videos and they said they vastly improved CoreLocation, but how is my iPhone getting a correct informations?

**TL;DR:** It works. I am just wondering how.

Comment: CoreLocation uses both GPS and iBeacons for positioning.  The path Apple seems to be taking is that you would use GPS for positioning outdoors, then it would switch to indoor position using iBeacons when the device detects them.  These geo anchors would allow you to translate the points between x/y and lat/long easily.

Comment: @Fengson did you find any solution for your problem.I'm also having the issue in indoor navigation using corelocation. I have used the ibeacons as well for this but did't get accurate result.

Answer (score 7):

Big companies, especially map providers such as Apple, Google, etc. gather information about all Wi-Fi access points (AP). They use so-called crowdsourcing technology in order to estimate position of AP by combining GPS coordinates with recieved signal strength (RSS) from all visible APs.

Once user requests a fix on their location, they send to server a list of all the MAC (media access control) addresses associated with wireless hot spots available within range to be checked against a database of those addresses. Then trilateration technique is used, that is fused with positional data provided by smartphone internal sensors (accelerometer, gyros, magnetometer, barometer). But this approach still suffer from lack of accuracy that is 7-20 meters so far depending from number of visible APs and quality of the sensors.
Learm more [here](http://rc3.org/2011/04/27/how-apple-uses-crowd-sourcing-to-find-your-location/), or [here](http://www.itbusiness.ca/news/google-apple-tap-crowdsourcing-to-map-out-wifi-locations/15658).

In order to have 1-5 meters accuracy, it's required to have additional correcting information. State of the art is to use bluetooth beacons. Given their coordinates it is possible to estimate user's position. Nowadays there are plenty of companies who develop this technology e.g. [Navigine](http://www.navigine.com), [indoors](http://www.indoo.rs), [nextome](http://www.nextome.org/).

Comment: Mapato is one of such companies delivering Indoor Positioning Systems based on state-of-the art BLE based technology and using Artificial Intelligence to reach higher accuracy (1-3m).

Answer (score 1):

CoreLocation uses GPS when outdoors, and WiFi access points (APs) when indoors (when mapped, otherwise you're getting GPS which isn't very good when indoors). CoreLocation uses iBeacons for proximity positioning, not for giving you a lat/lon. That is, you can use CoreLocation to say "When I get close to this iBeacon let me know". For WiFi positioning to work, you must upload floor plans to Apple, get them converted to their IMDF format, then use a surveying tool to fingerprint your indoor location. Only then will CoreLocation actually leverage the WiFi APs to give you an accurate indoor location (3-5 meter accuracy).